# How to add string before and after each regex matched groups in Python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a string and a regex with several groups. I want to add some string before and after each matched group. How can I do it? Below is the demo code only used to help describe my question.

```
data = "aa11bb123cc3333dd12eeeff3"
regex = re.compile(r"([a-z])\1(\d)(\d)(?=[a-z])")
```

The expected result is (using `<` and `>` to surround the matched groups):

```
<a>a<1><1>bb123cc3333<d>d<1><2>eeeff3
```

Please also consider regex group like `(\d)*` and I don't know how many groups beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your current regex `([a-z])\1(\d)(\d)(?=[a-z])` and replace it with this,

```
<\1>\1<\2><\3>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4HmWR/1)**

You can modify your code to use `re.sub` and get your expected output.

```
import re

data = "aa11bb123cc3333dd12eeeff3"
regex = re.compile(r"([a-z])\1(\d)(\d)(?=[a-z])")
print(re.sub(regex, r'<\1>\1<\2><\3>', data))
```

Prints like you expected,

```
<a>a<1><1>bb123cc3333<d>d<1><2>eeeff3
```

Also, as you updated your post, just clarifying that this regex `(\d)*` only has one group only and it is not that there is `*` outside the group and it will make number of groups multiple. `(\d)*` will behave same like `\d*` except the captured digit in the group will be just one and exactly the last one that matched.

Comment: What if the regex group is something like `(\d)*` and I don't know how many groups beforehand?

Comment: `(\d)*` is still one group only and number of groups in a regex remains the same as you write them. It's not that number of groups will vary but yes, the number of matches may multiple, but that won't be an issue. Like in your current regex, there are three groups and they will remain only three until you add more groups into it. Can you tell me precisely what issue are you facing?